# I can't type on my input using onChange, useState and spread operator on REACTJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux, javascript-objects

Here is how I set my initial state, I'm using pre-defined variables it counts the number of insurers then I create a textbox where they can fill up their names, ids and so on..

```
   function fields() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= pax; i++) {
            this[`insuredType${i}`] = state[`insuredType${i}`];
            this[`insuredBirthDate${i}`] = state[`insuredBirthDate${i}`];
            this[`insuredIdType${i}`] = state[`insuredIdType${i}`];
            this[`insuredIdNumber${i}`] = state[`insuredIdNumber${i}`];
            this[`insuredLastName${i}`] = state[`insuredLastName${i}`];
            this[`insuredFirstName${i}`] = state[`insuredFirstName${i}`];
        }
    }

    var object = new Array(pax);
    for (let i = 1; i <= pax; i++) {
        object = new fields();
    }

    const [insuredForm, setInsuredForm] = useState(object);

    const handleForm = (e) => {
        console.log([e.target.name]);
        setInsuredForm({ ...insuredForm, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(insuredForm);
    }, [insuredForm]);
```

Then here is my form, I think my problem is on my handle form, if I change it to defaultValue it works but it doesn't copy the value of the data to the textboxes when I onChange my insuredTypes to self.

```
    const tabList = [];
    const tabBody = [];
    //const tabForm = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= pax; i++) {
        tabList.push(
            <li key={i} className="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <a
                    className={i === 1 ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link"}
                    role="tab"
                    data-toggle="tab"
                    href={`#tab-${i}`}
                >
                    Insured {i}{" "}
                    {(errors["insuredType" + i] ||
                        errors["insuredBirthDate" + i] ||
                        errors["insuredLastName" + i] ||
                        errors["insuredFirstName" + i] ||
                        errors["insuredIdType" + i] ||
                        errors["insuredIdNumber" + i]) && (
                        <span role="alert" style={{ color: "#FC9191" }}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faExclamationCircle}
                                style={{ marginRight: 2 }}
                                size="1x"
                            />
                        </span>
                    )}
                </a>
            </li>
        );
        tabBody.push(
            <div
                key={i}
                className={i === 1 ? "tab-pane active" : "tab-pane"}
                role="tabpanel"
                id={`tab-${i}`}
            >
                {getTabContent(i)}
            </div>
        );
    }

    //console.log(tabForm);
    function getTabContent(id) {
        //if (insuredForm) console.log(insuredForm);
        let newDiv,
            type,
            tbirthDate,
            tidType,
            tidNumber,
            tlastName,
            tfirstName,
            treadOnly;

        let insuredType,
            insuredBirthDate,
            insuredIdType,
            insuredIdNumber,
            insuredLastName,
            insuredFirstName;

        type = insuredForm[`insuredType${id}`];

        tbirthDate =
            insuredForm[`insuredType${id}`] === "Self"
                ? birthDate
                : insuredForm[`insuredBirthDate${id}`];
        tidNumber =
            insuredForm[`insuredType${id}`] === "Self"
                ? idNumber
                : insuredForm[`insuredIdNumber${id}`];
        tlastName =
            insuredForm[`insuredType${id}`] === "Self"
                ? state.phLastName
                : insuredForm[`insuredLastName${id}`];
        tfirstName =
            insuredForm[`insuredType${id}`] === "Self"
                ? state.phFirstName
                : insuredForm[`insuredFirstName${id}`];
        tidType =
            insuredForm[`insuredType${id}`] === "Self"
                ? idType
                : insuredForm[`insuredIdType${id}`];

        treadOnly = insuredForm[`insuredType${id}`] === "Self" ? true : false;

        insuredType = {
            defaultValue: type,
            onChange: handleForm,
        };
        insuredBirthDate = {
            defaultValue: tbirthDate || "",
            readOnly: treadOnly,
            onChange: handleForm,
        };
        insuredIdType = {
            value: tidType || "",
            readOnly: treadOnly,
            onChange: handleForm,
        };
        insuredIdNumber = {
            value: tidNumber || "",
            readOnly: treadOnly,
            onChange: handleForm,
        };
        insuredLastName = {
            value: tlastName || "",
            readOnly: treadOnly,
            onChange: handleForm,
        };
        insuredFirstName = {
            value: tfirstName || "",
            readOnly: treadOnly,
            onChange: handleForm,
        };

        newDiv = (
            <form onChange={handleSubmit(handleCheck)}>
                <div
                    className="row mt-2"
                    style={{ marginBottom: -15 }}
                    key={id}
                >
                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                        {errors["insuredType" + id] && (
                            <p role="alert" className="errorHandler mb-0">
                                - {errors["insuredType" + id].message}
                            </p>
                        )}
                        {errors["insuredBirthDate" + id] && (
                            <p role="alert" className="errorHandler mb-0">
                                - {errors["insuredBirthDate" + id].message}
                            </p>
                        )}
                        {errors["insuredIdNumber" + id] && (
                            <p role="alert" className="errorHandler mb-0">
                                - {errors["insuredIdNumber" + id].message}
                            </p>
                        )}
                        {errors["insuredLastName" + id] && (
                            <p role="alert" className="errorHandler mb-0">
                                - {errors["insuredLastName" + id].message}
                            </p>
                        )}
                        {errors["insuredFirstName" + id] && (
                            <p role="alert" className="errorHandler mb-0">
                                - {errors["insuredFirstName" + id].message}
                            </p>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 py-3">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Type&nbsp;</label>
                                <select
                                    name={`insuredType${id}`}
                                    {...insuredType}
                                    ref={register({
                                        required: "Type of insurer is required",
                                    })}
                                    className={
                                        errors["insuredType" + id]
                                            ? "form-control is-invalid"
                                            : "form-control"
                                    }
                                >
                                    <option value="">Select type</option>
                                    <option>Self</option>
                                    <option>Other</option>
                                    <option>FAO</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Birthdate&nbsp;</label>
                                <input
                                    type="date"
                                    name={`insuredBirthDate${id}`}
                                    {...insuredBirthDate}
                                    ref={register({
                                        required: "Birthdate is required",
                                    })}
                                    className={
                                        errors["insuredBirthDate" + id]
                                            ? "form-control is-invalid"
                                            : "form-control"
                                    }
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Last Name&nbsp;</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name={`insuredLastName${id}`}
                                    placeholder="Last Name"
                                    {...insuredLastName}
                                    ref={register({
                                        required: "Last name is required",
                                    })}
                                    className={
                                        errors["insuredLastName" + id]
                                            ? "form-control is-invalid"
                                            : "form-control"
                                    }
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>First Name&nbsp;</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name={`insuredFirstName${id}`}
                                    placeholder="First Name"
                                    {...insuredFirstName}
                                    ref={register({
                                        required: "First name is required",
                                    })}
                                    className={
                                        errors["insuredFirstName" + id]
                                            ? "form-control is-invalid"
                                            : "form-control"
                                    }
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6 py-3">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Type of ID&nbsp;</label>
                                <select
                                    name={`insuredIdType${id}`}
                                    {...insuredIdType}
                                    ref={register({
                                        required: "ID is required",
                                    })}
                                    className={
                                        errors["insuredIdType" + id]
                                            ? "form-control is-invalid"
                                            : "form-control"
                                    }
                                >
                                    {listIdType}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>ID Number&nbsp;</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name={`insuredIdNumber${id}`}
                                    placeholder="ID Number"
                                    {...insuredIdNumber}
                                    ref={register({
                                        required: "ID number is required",
                                    })}
                                    className={
                                        errors["insuredIdNumber" + id]
                                            ? "form-control is-invalid"
                                            : "form-control"
                                    }
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
        return newDiv;
    }
```

Comment: this[`insuredType${i}`] = state[`insuredType${i}`]; <-- This is crazy.  Use an array of objects.

Comment: but it is working, here is the sample console.log(object);

` 
fields = {
    insuredBirthDate1: "2020-03-01"
    insuredBirthDate2: "1990-03-01"
    insuredFirstName1: "new name"
    insuredFirstName2: "adads"
    insuredIdNumber1: "12344"
    insuredIdNumber2: "12344"
    insuredIdType1: "Passport"
    insuredIdType2: "Passport"
    insuredLastName1: "123"
    insuredLastName2: "414"
    insuredType1: "FAO"
    insuredType2: "Self" }
 `

Comment: I would have a component that renders each one of the insured and pass it props `values`, `setValues`, `remove`.  The parent component would have a state with an array of values objects, and could also add a new one or remove one.

Comment: Yes that definitely works, but my scenario is different, on my other page before this, user would set how many Adults and Children to see the price then when they submit they will transfer here and the system will count how many adult and children the user inputted then creates a multiple forms for their names, ids and id numbers automatically contained in tabs. There will be no option to increase or decrease rows.